# PostGIS installation in Solus Budgie

Tags: postgresql, postgis-2.0, linux

Am new in Solus Budgie and am trying to install PostGIS have tried to look for any sources that has an article on same but no results.
anyone with a solution.

Comment: what have you tried? what seems to be the problem?

Comment: checking on possible articles on PostGIS  and from the solus community

Answer (score 0):

Solus uses PiSi package manager (eopkg). Looks like there is no eopkg for PostGIS available (yet).

A work-around could be using a Docker image:

https://hub.docker.com/r/postgis/postgis